# why does this code hangs on `await TransformBlock.Completion`

Tags: c#, .net-core, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

the following code blocks on `await loader.Completion;`

I just can't figure out why?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace tests {
    class Program {
        static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            Planner pl = new Planner();
            Console.WriteLine(await pl.Count());
        }
    }

    public class Planner {
        private TransformBlock<int, string[]> loader;
        private int _im = 0;

        public Planner(int im = 5) {
            _im = im;
            loader =
                new TransformBlock<int, string[]>(
                    async i => {
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                        return new string[] { i.ToString() };
                    }
               );
        }

        public async Task<long> Count() {
            foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(1, _im))
                loader.Post(i);

            //loader.Complete(), same blocking
            await loader.Completion;
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two problems here.

**1)** You didn't tell the block you've finished posting so `Completion` will never be signalled.

You need to call `loader.Complete()` first :

```
loader.Complete();
await loader.Completion;
```

**2)** The TransformBlock's output has nowhere to go so the block *can't* complete. A block can't reach the `Completed` state until its output buffer is cleared. If you don't care about the output an ActionBlock. Otherwise you'll have to link the block to something else, like a `BufferBlock<string[]>`, eg :

```
var results=new BufferBlock<string[]>();

loader.LinkTo(results);

...
loader.Complete();
await loader.Completion;
```

Completing one block won't propagate to other linked blocks unless you set the `PropagateCompletion` options in the link's options. In this case though there's no reason to propagate completion to the BufferBlock